# Ruby: Check if a program is installed in windows remote host

Tags: ruby, linux, windows

I need to test if a series of applications is installed in a linux/unix based host and in a windows host.
So obviously, in unix/linux is as easy as ssh-ing the host an run `$ which $cmd` like:

```
    def valid_util?(cmd, user, host, pass)
      begin
        result = nil
        Timeout::timeout(10) do
          Net::SSH.start( host.to_s, user.to_s, :password => pass.to_s) do |ssh|
            result = ssh.exec!(cmd.to_s)
          end
        end
      rescue Timeout::Error
        raise TimeoutError, 'SSH connection timeout!'
      end
      !result.nil?
    end
```

How can I achieve something similar in windows? Can anyone help me figuring this out?

Comment: Running `which $cmd` tells you only that *A* command with that name exists in the path. It doesn't tell you if it is the command you want, because files can have duplicate names and can exist in two places in the path. The command you want might not be in the right location, a hint that it's not really what you want, or it might be in something like /usr/local/bin and have the same name but entirely different functionality. You need to use a MD5 or some similar mechanism to confirm it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @theTinMan I know this is not fully correct but it fixes the purpose for now. Currently the goal is to have the "skeleton" of the app and then we will develop each functionality accordingly

Answer (score 0):

@skimisha

Hmm, maybe this approach would help:

- Use samba to connect to windows from linux (you can use [ruby/SMB](http://rubysmb.sourceforge.net/intro.php)).
- Once connected, you may use samba to browse the server and then based on results locally assert if the applications in questions have been installed.

BUT, if your use case is bit more complex (e.g. checking windows registry, etc.) and you must fire-off a command to check (similar to what you are doing against linux remote hosts), you may:

- setup ssh on windows using cygwin and then remotely execute .bat or .cmd files.
- try using [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/)